# Contract Development Problem in Parity

Tags: contract-development, parity

I run Parity on the command line using:

```
parity --chain dev
```

I run this so I can develop and test smart contracts. The problem is, whenever I try to develop a Smart Contract by clicking Contract -> Develop, the connection closes and this error shows up on the command line

```
2017-08-31 13:08:04  WS Error <Io(Error { repr: Os { code: 10054, message: "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host." } })>
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

**EDIT:** I installed it using the Parity installer for Windows.

Comment: Which Parity Version are you running? 1.7.0?

Comment: Yes. It's latest version.

Comment: Might be worth a bug report on GitHub.

Comment: @5chdn Has the issue been created? It continues to exist in windows platform for parity//1.8.1-beta